How do you calculate the conditional heteroscedasticity $\mathrm{Var}\left( \epsilon |X=x \right) $in a logit model?
I am currently reading the book Nonparametric and Semiparametric Models, where it discusses conditional heteroscedasticity with the following formula. However, I'm not sure how this formula is derived.


Tue authors literally mentioned they are "consider[ing]" that form to show how the violation of homoscedasticity affects the estimation as they plotted the two corresponding link functions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks! If we don't consider heteroscedasticity, the variance is $ \text{Var}(\zeta) $. However, the author takes heteroscedasticity into account, as shown in the form presented in the picture.@User1865345
